# How can I silence the "unused parameter" warning?

Tags: c++, warnings

I am cleaning all the warning for given codes.(Which means I am not fully understand each line logic). "[-Wunused-parameter]" is enabled and shall not be turned off.

And for "unused parameter", we usually just use "_ _ *attribute* _ _((unused))".

While for following functions, I can't use that above trick.

```
void fun(int* a =0){
    ----variable ptr a is not used at all----
}
```

Any good idea to have a clean solution to remove the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This easiest way is not to name the parameter:

```
void fun(int* =0){
    //...
}
```